# Powershell Get-SCVirtualDiskDrive generates a Common Language Specification (CLR) error

Tags: .net, powershell, virtual-machine, clr, virtualization

When running the Get-SCVirtualDiskDrive command from the VirtualMachineManager module in no particularly special way.

```
Get-SCVirtualDiskDrive -VMMServer $VMMServer -VM $VMName
```

I recieve a Common Language Specific (CLS) error

**format-default : The field or property: "Lun" for type: "Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.VirtualDiskDrive" differs only in letter casing from the field 
or property: "LUN". The type must be Common Language Specification (CLS) compliant.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotACLSComplaintProperty,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand**

I am having great difficulty trying to get this command to work from the few tips I can find online about .NET and PowerShell

This line of code works

```
$method1 = [Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.VirtualDiskDrive].GetMethod("get_LUN")
```

I really expected this line of code to return something but no, it returns nothing ...

```
$method2 = [Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.VirtualDiskDrive].GetMethod("get_Lun")
```

Beyond getting this line to work, the aim of the script is to expand the virtual machines primary VHD. I am really hoping someone can help here, it is not the first time I have ran into the problem, but this time, it is unavoidable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because I am running Powershell version 4 and the virtualmachinemanager module is only compatiable up to version 2.

Leaving two options

- Uninstall the Window Management Framework to degrade Powershell to version 2
- Use Start-Process to run a script as Powershell version 2

*Start-Process -File PowerShell.exe -Argument "-Version 2 -noprofile -noexit -file test.ps1  $params"*

Not ideal and I hope someone can improve on this answer